# How to solve pair of nonlinear differential equations using Sympy

Tags: python-2.7, wolfram-mathematica, sympy, nonlinear-functions

I have a system of two coupled nonlinear differential equations 
[image]

for which I wrote the following code to get values of two functions using Sympy:

```
from sympy import *
t = symbols('t')
c, b, B, alp, mu = symbols('c b B alp mu', integer=True)
f, g = symbols('f g', cls=Function)
print(solve([Eq(f(t).diff(t)+c*f(t)+0.5*B*f(t)**2-b*g(t), 0), Eq(g(t).diff(t)+b*g(t)-c*f(t), (1-alp)*mu)], [f(t),g(t)]))
```

However, the results what I get is still in the form of derivatives, which cannot be used for my purpose. I also tried Mathematica for the same but it keeps on running indefinitely with no result. 
[image]
Can someone please suggest a solution to such a system using Sympy or Mathematica?

Comment: Can you provide your ode's in maths format along with other information?

Comment: Provide your _Mathematica_ code.

Comment: Added equation. I don't have access to _Mathematica_ right now so could not provide that.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your system very easily in *Mathematica* with `NDSolve` providing you with a numerical solution. But for this you will need to specify the numerical values for the parameters and two initial conditions. Here I choose random ones.

```
  ClearAll["Gobal"]
Eq1 = f'[t] + c1*f[t] + 0.5*B1*f[t]^2 - b1*g[t] == 0;
Eq2 = g'[t] + b1*g[t] - c1*f[t] == (1 - alp)*mu;
ibcs = {f[0] == 1, g[0] == 0};
sys = Join[{Eq1, Eq2}, ibcs];
B1 = 1; b1 = 1; c1 = 1; alp = 1; mu = 1;
sol1 = NDSolve[sys, {f[t], g[t]}, {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[{f[t], g[t]} /. sol1, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible get the output in form of implicit analytical equations instead of a plot?

Comment: @Ashish I am unable to produce an analytical solution to this non-linear coupled system.

Comment: Same here so far. I added _Mathematica_ implementation as well as commented.

Comment: @Ashish Why not numerical solution ?

Comment: because it's part of an analytical equation results from which has to be compared with numerical solution.

Comment: @Ashish If possible then Share your complete problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133183/discussion-between-mmm-and-ashish).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ParametricNDSolve to allow any number of parameters to be decided later.  Then use Manipulate to explore.  Here's sample code:

```
{fx, gx} = Block[ {f, g, c, \[Beta], b, \[Alpha], \[Mu], f0, g0, tmax},
   {f, g} /. ParametricNDSolve[ {
      f'[t] + c f[t] + 0.5 \[Beta] f[t]^2 - b g[t] == 0,
      g'[t] + b g[t] - c f[t] - (1 - \[Alpha]) \[Mu] == 0,
      f[0] == f0, g[0] == g0
      }, {f, g}, {t, tmax}, {c, \[Beta], b, \[Alpha], \[Mu], f0, g0, 
      tmax} ]
   ];
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[ {fx[c, \[Beta], b, \[Alpha], \[Mu], f0, g0, 2^
     ln2tmax][t], 
   gx[c, \[Beta], b, \[Alpha], \[Mu], f0, g0, 2^ln2tmax][t]},
  {t, 0, 2^ln2tmax} ],
 {{c, 1}, -1, 1, 0.05},
 {{\[Beta], 1}, -1, 1, 0.05},
 {{b, 1}, -1, 1, 0.05},
 {{\[Alpha], 1}, -1, 1, 0.05},
 {{\[Mu], 1}, -1, 1, 0.05},
 Delimiter,
 {{f0, 1}, -1, 1, 0.05},
 {{g0, 1}, -1, 1, 0.05},
 Delimiter,
 {{ln2tmax, 0}, -3, 10, 0.5}
 ]
```